# I can't get the file name from the File Input @angular/material component

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't get the file name from the File Input @angular/material component
app.component.html

```
<div class="col-6">
    <mat-form-field>
      <ngx-mat-file-input [formControl]="fileControl"
                          placeholder="Выберите файл"
      >
        <mat-icon ngxMatFileInputIcon>folder</mat-icon>
      </ngx-mat-file-input>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

The example is taken from the documentation for this component, so I did not change anything in it.
Here are the modules that are in the file app.module.ts

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  CommonModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatInputModule,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule,
  NgxMatFileInputModule,
],
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  fileName: string;
  fileControl: FormControl;
  // files: any;
  files: FormControl;
  constructor() {
    this.fileName = '';
    this.fileControl = new FormControl(this.files);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fileControl.valueChanges.subscribe((files: FormControl) => {
      console.log('valueChanges OK ');
      this.files = files;
      console.log('file = ' + this.files.value);
      fileName = this.files.value;    //error!!!
    })
  }
}
```

How do I get the file name here:

```
fileName = this.files.value  ???
```

I took this example as a basis. [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-ngx-mat-file-input?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)
I removed everything unnecessary from there. I left only the code that is in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this solution with your repository!

**app.component.ts file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  fileControl: FormControl;
  public file;
  filename = '';

  constructor() {
    this.fileControl = new FormControl(this.file);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fileControl.valueChanges.subscribe((file: File) => {
      this.file = file;
      this.filename = file.name;
      console.log('fileName = ' + this.filename);
    })
  }
}
```

**app.component.html file:**

```
<div class="col-6">
    <mat-form-field>
        <ngx-mat-file-input [formControl]="fileControl">
            <mat-icon ngxMatFileInputIcon>folder</mat-icon>
        </ngx-mat-file-input>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: here it gives the error 
"Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Comment: @alexSerg Can you try to write console.log(control); inside the subscription ?
 The browser will write all the information of the object and we can try to understand the error

Comment: added, here's what he writes:
File {}
__proto__: File

Comment: I really don't know what is wrong, can you give us the repository of your ngx-mat-file-input? I also modify my answer giving you all code

Comment: I added a link to the original example

Comment: I tried that on stackblitz.com and it works with no problem to me, i modified my answer.

Comment: But in your answer, I don't see how I can assign the variable fileName = this.files. ???

Comment: I correct it, i bind the filename with the form control and put it in the subscription, sorry!

Comment: But how to work with it further? I add this code 
console.log('fileName = ' + this.filename);
and the console writes to me:
"fileName = [object File]"
And I need to see the file name

Comment: @alexSerg in my case `this.filename` was a string variable if you are trying to get the filename from the object file you need to do `console.log('fileName = ' + this.filename.name);` or you can log only the object so the browser will print it like a "tree diagram".

Answer (score 1):

Use  within reactive form.
It will give you back an object with a 'files' array.

**Wrap input element in form**

```
<form *ngIf="fileForm" [formGroup]="fileForm">
     <mat-form-field>
      <ngx-mat-file-input [formControl]="fileControl" placeholder="Выберите файл">
        <mat-icon ngxMatFileInputIcon>folder</mat-icon>
      </ngx-mat-file-input>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**And in TS component file write selector**

```
const file_form: FileInput = this.fileForm.get('fileControl').value;
```

Comment: I get an error on FileInput and this.fileFrom.

Comment: What kind of error? Did you registered ReactiveFormsModule in the module section?

Comment: I added a list of models